# Pip SSLError only in virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, ssl-certificate, virtualenv, python-packaging

I'm trying to set up a virtual environment for a coworker. I've never had any troubles installing Python packages via Pip, not in global nor in an environment. However, he is not able to install any packages in the environment. He can install them globally, however.

The error is:
"Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=pypi.org, port=443): Max retries exceed with url /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL Module is not available.")) - skipping"

We frist created the environment before installing any packages whatsoever. Then we deleted the environment, installed some packages (requests) and created a new environment. This did not help.

We tried

```
pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

which did not help either with the same error message.

I'm running out of ideas, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Install the package with the `config --global http.sslVerify false` statement

Comment: Also, sometime during April 2018, the Python Package Index was migrated from pypi.python.org to pypi.org. This means "trusted-host" commands using the old domain no longer work, but you can add both.